# How to update a Label inside while loop in tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, python-2.x

I am trying to update label of a window in tkinter inside a while loop but the text is not updating.Below is the code.

```
from Tkinter import *

window=Tk();
text1=StringVar();
text1.set("Waiting for Button Press...");

def main():
    while True:
          if condition:'''The condition is GPIO READ statement but for simplicity I have used condition'''
             text1.set("IN Button Pressed.Loading Camera.");
             window.update()

lbl=Label(window,text=text1.get());
lbl.pack();
window.after(5000,main);
window.mainloop();
```

Comment: A `while` loop like you have interferes with Tkinter's own `mainloop()`—so the main problem is you can't do what you want to do using one like this. If you want to periodically check some condition (and possibly update the text of a `Label`), you'll need to use the `after()` method repeatably to get that to happen. Also note that Python does not require a `;` at the end of each statement.

Answer (score 2):

To update the text of a label dynamically you can use `lbl["text"]`

I can not follow your code completely(because I'm too new to this...) but I think you can use this and rework the code that way.

```
from Tkinter import *
window=Tk()
text1 = "Waiting for Button Press..."
lbl=Label(window,text=text1)
lbl.pack()

def main():
    while True:
          if condition:'''The condition is GPIO READ statement but for simplicity I have used condition'''
             lbl["text"] = "IN Button Pressed.Loading Camera."

window.after(5000,main)
window.mainloop()
```

Not sure if you need the `window.update()`

Answer (score 1):

As I said in a comment, using a `while` loop like you're attempting to do will interfere with Tkinter's own `mainloop()`. To do something repeatedly without stopping the Tkinter GUI's main loop is often accomplished by using the universal [`after()`](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/universal.html) method (which you seem to know about already).

In addition, if you set the `textvariable=` (instead if `text=`) option of the `Label` widget to the `StringVar`, changes to the Tkinter Variable will **automatically** update the `Label`'s appearance. Here's a little documentation I found about using [Tkinter Variable Classes](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/variable.htm).

Here's example code showing how to accomplish your goal by implementing these suggestions:

```
from random import randint
from Tkinter import *

MS_DELAY = 500  # Milliseconds between updates.

window = Tk()
text1 = StringVar()

def gpio_read():
    """ Simulate GPIO READ. """
    return randint(0, 3)

def check_condition():
    if gpio_read() == 0:
        text1.set("IN Button Pressed.Loading Camera.")
    else:
        text1.set("Waiting for Button Press...")

    window.after(MS_DELAY, check_condition)  # Schedule next check.

lbl = Label(window, textvariable=text1)  # Link to StringVar's value.
lbl.pack()

window.after(MS_DELAY, check_condition)  # Schedule first check.
window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

The `condition` is set to `False`, and is changed to `True` in `main`.

After 5 seconds, the `change_if_condition` method is called, `condition` is checked, and if found `True`, the label textvariable is changed, and automatically updates the label.

```
from tkinter import *


def change_if_condition():
    if condition:
        text1.set("IN Button Pressed.Loading Camera.")


def main():
    global condition
    condition= True
    window.after(5000, change_if_condition)


window = Tk()

text1 = StringVar()
text1.set("Waiting for Button Press...")

lbl = Label(window, textvariable=text1)   # use textvariable, so the displayed text is changed when the variable changes
lbl.pack()

condition = False

main()

window.mainloop()
```